# Notification bar in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create a Notification Bar similar to Facebook or StackExchange.

I want it to display notifications with numbers and a drop down panel with some information.

[image]
[image]

Can someone provide an example or a tutorial on how to create that in Ruby on Rails or Javascript/jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably done as a two stage process:

- Get a counter of outstanding/unread notifications. Display in header as a link.
- Add a jQuery handler that will load the messages via AJAX either on click or on hover depending on preferences.

The first part is simple, you just call a method on your association if you have a scope established:

```
<%= link_to(@user.notifications.unread.count, user_notifications_path(@user), :class => 'notifications') %>
```

The next part involves patching together something with jQuery, perhaps like this:

```
$('.notifications').click(function() {
  $('#notifications').load(this.href);
  return false;
});
```

You'll need to have a specific view that will render into that `#notification` block.

Comment: and that view will first call the controller? And show the results ?

Comment: You're linking through to a controller and action pair that would render the actual notifications, yes. You can even test this without AJAX by clicking on the link and checking that the correct HTML is displayed.

Comment: Do you know if I can find a complete tutorial somewhere?